# Phrase search "prune all refs" fails

Tags: bug, search

Supposedly you can search for exact phrases by putting a sequence of words in quotes.  Well, I searched for "prune all refs", looking for an explanation of a git command-line switch which is poorly documented.  It gave 0 results.

So I kept searching by other means and ran across the exact question I wanted, and it did contain the exact sequence "prune all refs"!  Why did this not match my phrase search??

I even did a copy-paste from the question's text to make sure I didn't type something wrong, and eliminate the possibility that there was a non-standard character of some sort, but still no match.

Comment: The search engine took your "prune all refs" search as an order and pruned all the refs. So you got 0 results because the refs were all gone.

Comment: @Louis: Haha... that's clearer than the git documentation... and funnier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24127061/git-reflog-all-how-does-this-prune-refs), it would have been because the text could only be found within a code block. A good reason to be picky about formatting!

Comment: Sorry, your answer is not clear to me at all...  Are you saying that search strings will never match any text inside code blocks?  That seems a little unfortunate.  Is this documented somewhere?  And how would being picky about formatting help?  Picky how?  What would have been the ideal way for the question to have been written and for me to search in order to have a happy ending?

Comment: @AgentFriday: Yes, I’m saying that; maybe; I don’t know where or if it’s documented. Picky about formatting, not formatting help, and the correct way to format documentation excerpts is with a quote, which is how I edited the question. The search will work at some point in the future when it stops being cached, and you can try it now at https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%22prune%20all%22.